# Detect ipad virtual keyboard events

Tags: ipad, keyboard-events

I am writing an HTML/CSS web app for the iPad.  How do I catch the Tab event when the user uses the 'Next' button on the virtual keyboard to tab between fields.  I want to capture this event, cancel it, and use my own custom handler.

Thanks